# TypeError: wrong number of arguments when passing list to Python function

Tags: python, list, inheritance, typeerror

I have a Python parent class which includes a function which is passed a list, and then checks whether a particular element (key) is included within it:

```
class Output():

    def __init__(self, data):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def checkCal(self, options):
        if "calendar" in options:
            #do some stuff
```

There is then another class which inherits from it:

```
import output

class CSVOutput(output.Output):

    # blah blah blah

    def theFunction(self, data):
        data["first"] = "hello"
        data["second"] = "calendar"
        self.checkCal(self, data)
```

However, the final line results in a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: checkCal() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I presume that the number of arguments given is three because one is `self` and the list contains two elements. But I should be able to pass a list to a function as a single object, shouldn't I? I won't always know how many elements there are. I've done plenty of reading but can't seem to find anyone who has been experiencing this particular problem before (which makes it highly likely I'm just doing it wrong!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include `self` when calling a method on an instance:

```
self.checkCal(data)
```

suffices.

Python produces a *method* object whenever you reference a function name on an instance, and that object will call the original function passing in the instance as the first argument. See the [descriptor protocol HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) for all the technical details.

Comment: see also https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod